# How do I search through an excel column for a row name and then get the row data in Excel?

Tags: excel

Example:

I have a table (space = new column)

Spain 5 2 8 0

Italy 2 8 8 1

China 1 7 7 7

Canada 0 2 0 5

Every time I paste a new table in, the countries will be ranked in order of the first number. Largest at the top.

This is what I want to do:

Get the rows and sort them into continents. Europe, Asia and North America.

How do I find the country name in the first column and copy the row data to another table?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have a Country||Continent||Index table ("MapTable"), I would:
1.- Using formula: polulate such "MapTable" with vlookup/index+match/sumif from your "Paste table" and sort by Continent.

2.- Using PowerQuery: I would get the "Paste table", merge it with the "MapTable", sort within PowerQuery by index, and export to a new table (with or without continent/index columns).

3.- VBA... I probably wouldn´t use it.